# Remove/Hide Save,Save and add another buttons for one of my models in admin panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created a custom button for my application in Django admin panel by overriding the template.I was wondering if there is any way I could remove the save and save and add another button from my django admin panel.I just want my custom button on that page.Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you define your own admin template specific for the model (you can also override the standard one but this makes it more clear):

```
class AourAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'admin/my_app/my_model/modified_change_list.html'
```

Then you can change the relevant lines in the template

```
   .......      
   {% block result_list %}

      {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
      {% result_list cl %}
      {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
  {% endblock %}
  ........
```

Make sure the path for the template is found.